# $\small| U-\frac{m}{n}\small| \leq \frac{1}{n^3}$

Tags: probability, inequality, stochastic-processes, uniform-distribution

Let $U$ be uniform distributed in $[0,1]$ . Show that with probability $1$ there's maximum a finite amount of $n \in \mathbb N$, so that the inequality

$\small| U-\frac{m}{n}\small| \leq \frac{1}{n^3}$

is true for $m \in \mathbb N$.

---

I have tried for two days and I couldn't solve it.

Comment: Perhaps Borel-Cantelli would be useful?  If you can show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|U - \frac{m}{n}| \leq \frac{1}{n^3}) < \infty$ for any $m$, Borel-Cantlli would give you the desired result.

Comment: This is a special case of Khinchin's theorem in diophantine approximation; I'm sure the proof is as elegant as the theorem.

Comment: I dont understand how that leads to the solution

Comment: A more rigorous phrasing of the result to be proven is that almost surely, $A_n$ happens for finitely many $n$, where $A_n=[\exists m,\,|U-m/n|\leqslant1/n^3]$. Then indeed the easy part of Borel-Cantelli lemma yields this directly since, for each $n$, $$P(A_n)\leqslant\sum_{m=0}^nP(m/n-1/n^3\leqslant U\leqslant m/n+1/n^3)\leqslant(n+1)2/n^3,$$ hence the series $\sum\limits_nP(A_n)$ converges, qed.